# Operator Overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, output

I'm Confused about a topic regarding operator overloading. See the following code:

```
#include <iostream>;

class Vectors {
public:
    int x, y;
    Vectors() {};
    Vectors(int a,int b) {
        x = a, y = b;
    }
    Vectors operator+(Vectors aso) {
        Vectors brandNew;
        std::cout << "ASO X " << aso.x << std::endl;
        std::cout << "ASO Y " << aso.y << std::endl;
        brandNew.x = brandNew.x + aso.x;
        brandNew.y = brandNew.y + aso.y;
        return (brandNew);
    };
};
int main() {
    Vectors v1(2,3);
    Vectors v2(4,5);
    Vectors v3;
    v3 = v1 + v2;

    std::cout << "Vector V3 X : " << v3.x << std::endl;
    std::cout << "VECTOR V3 Y : " << v3.y << std::endl;
}
```

When I print aso.x, it y gives me 4 and 5. What I want to do is add both v1 and v2; meaning the x of v1 and v2, and the y of v1 and v2. Then, pass it into a Vectors object and return that object.

How do I accomplish that, given what I have above?

Comment: Try brandNew.x = x + aso.x ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably meant

```
Vectors operator+(const Vectors& aso) {
        Vectors brandNew;
        std::cout << "ASO X " << aso.x << std::endl;
        std::cout << "ASO Y " << aso.y << std::endl;
        brandNew.x = x + aso.x;
        brandNew.y = y + aso.y;
        return (brandNew);
    };
```

or

```
Vectors operator+(const Vectors& aso) {
    Vectors brandNew(x + aso.x, y + aso.y);
    std::cout << "ASO X " << aso.x << std::endl;
    std::cout << "ASO Y " << aso.y << std::endl;
    return (brandNew);
};
```

---

As from your comment

> But about if there were three.

Chain the operators like

```
int main() {
    Vectors v1(2,3);
    Vectors v2(4,5);
    Vectors v3(7,11);
    Vectors v4;
    v4 = v1 + v2 + v3;

    std::cout << "Vector V4 X : " << v4.x << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Vector V4 X : " << v4.y << std::endl;
}
```

See [<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/87e6f6393fd02dc9)

Comment: That worked but how? Explain like the process of brandNew.x = x + aso.x;
        brandNew.y = y + aso.y;

Comment: think of it like brandNew.x = this->x + aso.x;

Comment: Im Confused here.. what is x?

Comment: You wan't to have the actual member values of your instance involved (`x` is equivalent to `this->x` in this context.

Comment: @AmanuelBogale look at the table here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators to see how operator overload with 2 arguments works

Comment: Ok I Understand the first part compeltely. But about if there were three. show me that in like the way you did on Method 1. Thankyou!

Comment: @AmanuelBogale As you see in the demo it was based on method 1. But it shouldn't matter, method 2 will work equally well.

Comment: `Vectors operator+(const Vectors &aso) { return Vectors(x+aso.x, y+aso.y);  }` should also work.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use external operator+ :

```
class Vectors {
public:
    int x, y;
    Vectors() {};
    Vectors(int a,int b) {
        x = a, y = b;
    }

    friend Vectors operator+(const Vectors& v1, const Vectors& v2);
};

Vectors operator+(const Vectors& v1, const Vectors& v2) {
        Vectors brandNew;
        brandNew.x = v1.x + v2.x;
        brandNew.y = v1.y + v2.y;
        return (brandNew);
    };

int main() {
    Vectors v1(2,3);
    Vectors v2(4,5);
    Vectors v3;
    v3 = v1 + v2;

    std::cout << "Vector V3 X : " << v3.x << std::endl;
    std::cout << "VECTOR V3 Y : " << v3.y << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: @AmanuelBogale _"Do you think i should learn all these keyworkds lol?"_ Sure, these keywords are all essential and just at beginners level.

Comment: @AmanuelBogale actually `friend` is not needed here, but if you would make x and y private then it allows external operator+ to access x and y even if they are private. btw. what book are you reading? classes / overloading in c++ primier is on ~560 page

Comment: Without the friend keyword.. its a whole lot better .. And lol im actually watching viedos. Idk if this is a good plan but i plan on finishing this tutorial. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yUtY63Fk3hM&index=31&list=PLS1QulWo1RIYSyC6w2-rDssprPrEsgtVK  .. Then Finishing NewBoston C++ Tutorial.... Then Finish another 100 episode tutorial... then finish like 3 books lol. One of my book TODO List is Obviously C++ Primeier. which i have online for free... Im Still Beggining! And i tottaly Understand you on the friend keyword.. most of the time i will declare my "properties" private... So its essenc

Comment: @AmanuelBogale You should stop trying to learn c++ from youtube tutorials. Get a good book!

Comment: Are you sure @πάνταῥεῖ ... Books for me normally are overwhelming.. so i normally study them when i have a good foundation already..

Comment: @AmanuelBogale _"so i normally study them when i have a good foundation already.."_ Strange? Won't a book (at least a good one) give you a good foundation that you always can backup again? I found that video tutorials are confusing, and it's easy to miss something in an eye blink or a bad edit jump in such video.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ .... Hmm .. What do you think πάνταῥεῖ? I Mean i already started this tutorial.. might as well finish it and go to the books!

Comment: This doesn't have to be a chicken and egg problem. If you can't understand the answer to the question without understanding the terminology, learn the terminology. You may not understand what the terminology means, so then you should write a bit of code playing with it. If you still don't get it, ask questions about the bit of code. Don't try and write your own vector before you understand the concepts you need to understand in order to write the vector. You'll go nuts that way.

Answer (score 1):

Your code creates the new `Vectors` object `brandNew` and then adds the values of it which are initialised to 0 to the values inside the `Vectors` object you passed in instead of the values in the current object. Which is why when you add `v1` to`v2` the result has the same values as those inside `v2`.

Replace

```
brandNew.x = brandNew.x + aso.x;
brandNew.y = brandNew.y + aso.y;
```

with

```
brandNew.x = x + aso.x;
brandNew.y = y + aso.y;
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't initialized the `x` and `y` members of `brandNew`. You'll get random results.

```
Vectors operator+(Vectors aso) {
    Vectors brandNew;
    std::cout << "ASO X " << aso.x << std::endl;
    std::cout << "ASO Y " << aso.y << std::endl;
    brandNew.x = x + aso.x;
    brandNew.y = y + aso.y;
    return (brandNew);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct definition of +operator is the following:

```
  Vectors &operator+(const Vectors& aso)
  {
    std::cout << "ASO X " << aso.x << std::endl;
    std::cout << "ASO Y " << aso.y << std::endl;
    x = x + aso.x;
    y = y + aso.y;
    return (*this);
  }
```

above code does not need temporary variable and also does not do unnecessary copy of parameters as is passed by reference.